# How to update Odoo to major version

Tags: odoo

I have an Odoo instance (13) installed from GitHub reps and want to update to version 14.

I followed the steps here [1](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/14.0/setup/update.html):
Enter the odoo base code in /opt/odoo/odoo

```
git fetch
git rebase --autostash
```

Then i updated the modules starting the service with the options "-u all -d mydatabase"

```
su odoo -c "/opt/odoo/venv/bin/python3 /opt/odoo/odoo/odoo-bin -c /etc/odoo-file.conf -u all -d mydatabase"
```

After a while, when the process finished the Odoo version is still 13.

There's no customizations in code and database, and there's no true records there.

I would like to know if there's a step i missed or the correct way to update Odoo.

Thanks

Comment: upgrading from 13 to 14 is probably an uncharted territory yet :)

Comment: after fetching or fetching -all, you need to do : git checkout 14.0

Answer (score 1):

First `git branch` to see what is actually checked out.

If you are using self hosted community edition of Odoo then you have to do manual data migration before the upgrade.
Backup everything and start with test environment. It will go wrong.

You have to know what data is in your database. And what changes are made to the Odoo.

there are tools and tips but not yet for ver 14
https://github.com/OCA/OpenUpgrade

Comment: I downloaded and see that version 14 to open upgrade is not ready yet, thanks for answer

Comment: They have a WIP ver 14 branch right now on the OCA